# php cake find() using OR condition

Tags: php, cakephp

I need a basic "or" in my if else condition in php cake.

```
$oTourRecords =  $this->Record->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'record.builder_name' => 'rey',
            'or' => array(
                'record.builder_name' => 'norbert',
            )
         )
     )
);
```

basically i need to get if the record contain builder_name = rey or "norbert"
this one returns null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
$oTourRecords =  $this->Record->find('all', array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'OR' => array(
                        'record.builder_name' => 'norbert',
                        'record.builder_name' => 'rey',
                    )
            )
         ));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in several ways:

```
$oTourRecords =  $this->Record->findAllByBuilderNameOrBuilderName('rey', 'norbert');

$oTourRecords =  $this->Record->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'OR' => array(
                    'record.builder_name' => 'norbert',
                    'record.builder_name' => 'rey',
                )
        )
     ));

$oTourRecords =  $this->Record->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array('record.builder_name IN ' => array('norbert','rey'))
 ));
```

Answer (score 1):

> You can also use `IN` to retrieve similar type of Data instead of `OR` conditions.

**Example :**

```
$oTourRecords =  $this->Record->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'record.builder_name IN'=>array(
                 'rey',
                 'norbert'
             )
         )
     )
);
```